# Stored Procedure Parameter not supplied

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

This is my model class same as table in database:

```
public class AttendanceModel
{
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Login As")]
        public string UserRole { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Mobile { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view file. If I have any error please let me know:

```
 @model AttendanceManagement.Models.AttendanceModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LoginForm";
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <!-- meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Art Sign Up Form Responsive Widget, Audio and Video players, Login Form Web Template, Flat Pricing Tables, Flat Drop-Downs, Sign-Up Web Templates,
        Flat Web Templates, Login Sign-up Responsive Web Template, Smartphone Compatible Web Template, Free Web Designs for Nokia, Samsung, LG, Sony Ericsson, Motorola Web Design" />
    <!-- /meta tags -->
    <!-- custom style sheet -->
    <link href="~/LoginStyles/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- /custom style sheet -->
    <!-- fontawesome css -->
    <link href="~/LoginStyles/css/fontawesome-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- /fontawesome css -->
    <!-- google fonts-->
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- /google fonts-->

</head>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <body>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <div class="w3l-login-form">
            <h2>Register Here</h2>
            <div class="w3l-form-group">
                <label>Usertype:</label>
                <div class="group">                    
                        <select id="txtUser" class="form-control">
                            <option>Admin</option>
                            <option>Teacher</option>
                            <option>Student</option>
                        </select>                    
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="w3l-form-group">
                <label>Email:</label>
                <div class="group">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required" id="txtEmail" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="w3l-form-group">
                <label>Password:</label>
                <div class="group">
                    <i class="fas fa-unlock"></i>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required" id="txtPassword" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="w3l-form-group">
                <label>Mobile:</label>
                <div class="group">
                    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No" required="required" id="txtMobile" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="button" id="btnRegister" value="register" onclick="Register()" />
        </div>
    </body>
}

@*@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}*@

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    function Register() {
        $("#btnRegister").val('Please wait..');
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Content("~/Attendance/Register")",
            data: { Usertype: $("#txtUser").val(), Email: $("#txtEmail").val(), Password: $("#txtPassword").val(), Mobile: $("#txtMobile").val() },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.StatusCode == 'OK') {
                    alert("Successfull login.");
                    window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/Attendance/LoginForm")';
                } else {
                    alert(data.Message);
                }
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
        $("#btnRegister").val('register');
    }
</script>
```

This is my controller stored procedure method. I have checked it many times cannot find the error in the stored procedure:

```
 private AttendanceModel insertUserdetails(AttendanceModel register)
 {
     string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AttendanceConnect"].ToString();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();

     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
     {
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("attendance_insert", con))
         {
             using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
             {
                 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pUserRole", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.UserRole;
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.Email;
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.Password;
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pMobile", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.Mobile;

                 da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                 con.Open();
                 da.Fill(dt);
             }
         }
     }

     if (dt != null && dt.Rows != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
     {
         register = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                     select new AttendanceModel()
                            {
                                UserId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["UserId"].ToString()),
                                UserRole = dr["UserRole"].ToString(),
                                Email = dr["Email"].ToString(),
                                Password = dr["Password"].ToString(),
                                Mobile = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Mobile"].ToString()),
                                isActive = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["isActive"].ToString())
                            }).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
     }

     return register;
 }
```

This is my stored procedure code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[attendance_insert] 
    @pUserRole varchar(10),
    @pEmail varchar(50),
    @pPassword varchar(50),
    @pMobile varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO AttendanceLogin (UserRole, Email, Password, Mobile, isActive) 
    VALUES (@pUserRole, @pEmail, @pPassword, @pMobile, 1)
END
```

[image: Image shows parameter not provided and very difficult to get hold of error. Have checked model class, database table, Procedure parameter many times.]
PLz help me to note error as I repeat this mistake always.

Comment: Please add the **complete and precise** error message(s) you're getting

Comment: You are missing the @ symbol when adding the parameters.  You need for example `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pUserRole", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.UserRole`.

Comment: @JonathanWillock that is not yet solving my issue.

Comment: Try replacing  `AddWithValue` with plain `Add` - AddWithValue expects the value as 2nd param, not the type

Comment: That stored procedure doesn't select anything, so there is nothing to fill a DataSet - use cmd.ExecuteNonQuery (and remove the DataAdapter)

Comment: Are you still getting the same error?

Answer (score 1):

You have committed two mistakes that's why you are getting "Parameter not supplied"

**First:**

In this class `AttendanceModel`, the **UserId** is not set as primary key. Hence the stored procedure is expecting its value.

**Second:**

In your controller, you are expecting `UserId` here:

```
UserId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["UserId"].ToString())
```

This will obviously cause the error as it is not able to find `UserId` and you are not passing it in your stored procedure.

What you can do is add a `[Key]` data annotation to make it primary key. This would autogenerate the primary key on that field and you will get rid of this error:

```
public class AttendanceModel
{
    [Key] // <-- Add this. You need to import using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Login As")]
    public string UserRole { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Mobile { get; set; }
}
```

And then check

EDIT:

Your code where you are inserting the data is incorrect. If you have used Stored Procedure, you need to pass "@pUserRole" whereas you have just passed pUserRole, and similar change in all  the variables. Look at the change below:

```
 using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
 {
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pUserRole", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.UserRole;
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.Email;
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.Password;
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pMobile", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.Mobile;

       da.SelectCommand = cmd;

       con.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
 }
```

Comment: You *might* be right (chances are quite high in this concrete case) - but I always find it kinda hard to **guess** what the error might be - it should really be the OP's job to **show us** the full error so we **know** what is wrong and what to suggest to fix it.

Comment: I have tried adding KEY annotation in model as well still the error continues to be same.